# setState on unmounted component error due as I need to use 2 hooks

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I using the std:accounts-ui library for Meteor with React. I need to redirect users to a new page when they register for the first time or login.

I have separate login and register pages, but as Im also using the accounts-facebook package users can login from the register page if they use the facebook button.

For this reason I need to use both onPostSignUpHook and onSignedInHook hooks. My code is working but when users sign up via email I get this error:

```
Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

Please check the code for the LoginForm component.


class Register extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { redirect: false };
    }

    handleRedirect() {
        if (this.state.redirect === false) {
            this.setState({ redirect: true });
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.redirect) return <Redirect to="/people/me" />;
        return (
            <div className="RegLog RegLog--register">
                <h1>Register</h1>
                <Accounts.ui.LoginForm
                    formState={STATES.SIGN_UP}
                    onPostSignUpHook={() => this.handleRedirect()}
                    onSignedInHook={() => this.handleRedirect()}
                />
                <p>
                    Already have an account?{' '}
                    <Link className="link" to="/login">
                        Login
                    </Link>
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Register;
```

Comment: As you might know, doing something like this `{() => this.handleRedirect()}` means this function will be executed on encounter, as opposed to this `{this.handleRedirect}`, which will simply pass the reference. So, because this function is called in the render method and the function itself sets the state, that is a problem because the component is still in the process of mounting

Comment: Which library are you using for routing?

Comment: @luboskrnac React router 4